# confound significantly different across groups

Tags: ancova, propensity-scores, predictor

I feel this has to come up quite frequently, but there seems to be little clarity in how to handle the problem. If you have a demographic variable (e.g. age, edu) that significantly differs across groups (and correlated to variables of interest) what is the best way of calibrating your groups so that you can then run analyses such as ANCOVA or Mult Reg etc? I found there are propensity scores that can be calculated through binary log regression, but I haven't been able to find what you do with those after. Do you just plug those into the ANCOVA, for intstance, as a covariate? I am trying to complete my dissertation in clinical psych and do not have an advanced understanding of statistics. If PS is the best option then how do you attain them through a multinomial reg. Syntax or point-and-click for SPSS is what i need.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, you can just plug the propensity score in as a covariate.

For the long answer see [this book](http://ssw.unc.edu/psa/index.php?q=content/shenyang-guo):